# How long does the PSP remember's it's state when the battery is removed

Tags: hardware, psp

i have 2 Batteries for my PSP 2000, i only recently learned that the problem with the first battery may have actually been the PSP not charging up via the power cable

when i was fiddling with batteries between my 2 PSPs i found that if i switch the batteries quickly the PSP would not fully rest (By asking me to re-input the current time/date)

so i am wondering, if i was in the middle of a game and notice the battery is low, i put the PSP on standby and take the battery out, how long do i have to replace the battery before the PSP looses it's state and resets (thus quitting out of my game)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal experience: swapping the batteries probably won't work, except you are extremely fast.

The PSP's date is kept because of an internal battery (pretty much like in every PC - BIOS battery). It takes some time till this one is fully depleted.

So: Once the power supply is cut (battery), the PSP does not hold enough charge, to keep the game running, even on standby.

What you could do - if you notice low battery, plug in the power supply and then swap the battery. Now, I don't know if the PSP can run with power supply only, so try it first.

Comment: it can, i was once playing my PSP 1000 without a battery because i had it in my PSP 2000 while i was waiting for Dissidia 012 to install to the memory stick (i was playing it on the TV before i got my new battery).....downside is that i think the DC-IN port on my PSP 2000 might be stuffed and that's why i was asking about battery switching, guess i have to think of a backup plan